# sql server join 3 tables, not in other column of third table

Tags: sql-server, join, notin

So, i have two tables which are connected by a third one. 
Something like:

First Table:

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+------------+
| box_column | code_column  | from_column  | to_column  |
+------------+--------------+--------------+------------+
|     12345  | sdsad1       |  madrid      | london     |
+------------+--------------+--------------+------------+
```

Second Table:

```
+-------------+--------------+
| code_column | truck_column |
+-------------+--------------+
| sdsad1      | truck1       |
| sdsad1      | truck2       |
| sdsad1      | truck3       |
+-------------+--------------+
```

Third Table:

```
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| truck_column | from_column | to_column |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| truck1       | madrid      | paris     |
| truck2       | paris       | calais    |
| truck3       | calais      | london    |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
```

---

after having a join,  just having the number of the box, is there any way i can distinct the  trucks that make the last leg (third table have london in the to_column)  and the others?

Comment: what do you mean by 'make the last leg .. and the others'

Comment: You need to clarify a little more as to what end result you are looking for. ultimately what information do you need to get out of the joins that you can not get out of the third table itself.

Comment: the first table says that a box is going from madrid to london for example. the third table is about the diferent trucks in which that box goes (not direct). i need to query by my box (first table box_column). and the query look where the box goes to (first table to_column) and returns the result in the third table that has the same value in the to_column.  if the box goes to london, i need the truck from the third table that goes to london and not the others.

Comment: Your model doesn't make sense.  You would want to record each leg in a table with the start and stop times. What if a truck brokedown half way to  London. And another truck going the other way picked up teh load and returned it to Calias and and then a third truck to the item to London. Then you have two London trips and possibly a truck that doesn't normally do the London run that might show truck 4 as Calis to Amsterdam in the truck table. You want to do this from real time what actually happened not from what the trucks are scheduled to normally do because that will change over time.

Comment: Suppose in May, truck 1 did the run to Paris, but it now March of the next year and that truck is out of service or is doing the run to London. How would you tell what truck did the run in May with this model? YOu need to do some reading about handling temporal data because this model is a failure waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1):

That is not very difficult to do, it's actually quite basic:

```
SELECT      *
FROM        dbo.code c
INNER JOIN  dbo.jointable j on c.code = j.code
INNER JOIN  dbo.truck t on j.truck = t.truck
WHERE       c.box = 12345
AND         c.[to] = t.[to]
```

Where code is your first table, jointable is your second table, and truck is your third table.

The output of this query is:

```
box    code    from    to      code    truck   truck   from    to
---------------------------------------------------------------------
12345  sdsad1  madrid  london  sdsad1  truck3  truck3  calais  london
```

To get only the truck as output, replace

```
SELECT    *
```

with

```
SELECT    t.truck
```

Last but not least: I'm not seeing any primary keys, nor foreign keys in your model. Maybe you left it out. If not, please use [keys and constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179610.aspx).